# Horizontal list inline styling works but css referencing does not

Tags: html, css, list, inline

Trying to make a horizontal list via the use of a CSS document. When I use inline sttyling the list displays as wanted but when I use CSS selectors, it doesn't. My CSS isn't being overwritten as I've also tested in JSBin.

```
#footer-list li {
  display: inline;
}

  <ul class="footer-list">
                <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">4</a></li>
            </ul>

  <ul>
                <li style="display:inline;"><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li style="display:inline;"><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li style="display:inline;"><a href="">3</a></li>
                <li style="display:inline;"><a href="">4</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use wrong selector, try "dot" instead of "hash"

```
.footer-list li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Dariusz Majchrzak stated, you are incorrectly using a '**#**' rather than a '**.**'

This is an issue because in CSS element **ID**'s are marked with a **#** whereas **classes** are marked with a **.** and here you are referencing a class "footer-list"

Had this been

id="footer-list"

than your original code of **#footer-list** would have worked as expected.